# Create a List of .bacpac Files in Azure Storage by Using BlobHierarchyItems

Tags: c#, azure-storage, winui-3

I'm obtaining a list of `.bacpac` file names in our Azure Storage to display them in a UI. The bacpacs are not located in one directory but are separated under more than a hundred (and growing) project-based locations. I've tested two methods below.

Method two seems to work fine, but it requires looping through all blobs.

*Method one is preferable* because it targets the correct project, limiting the number of blobs it loops through. But *that method is stuffing duplicate values* into the `.bacpac` file list (i.e., for one .`bacpac` file, it adds two identical items into the list). I checked Azure Storage and only saw one item.

Any idea why method one is creating duplicates and how to fix it? I don't want to just check the list to see if the item exists already, but understand the root cause and correct it there.

I'm using `Azure.Core` & `Azure.Storage` packages/namespaces.

```
   public static List<string> GetBackupFiles(string dbName)
    {
        string backupDirectory = dbName + "/dbbackups/";

        List<string> rv = new();

        BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = GetStorageAccount(_StorageConnectionString);
        BlobContainerClient contCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer);
        
        //METHOD ONE
        Azure.Pageable<BlobHierarchyItem> blobHierarchyItems = contCl.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.All,BlobStates.All, "/", backupDirectory);
        List<string> test = new();
        foreach(BlobHierarchyItem blobHierarchyItem in blobHierarchyItems)
        {
            if (blobHierarchyItem.IsBlob)
            {
                BlobItem blob = blobHierarchyItem.Blob;
                string path = blob.Name[..Math.Min(backupDirectory.Length, blob.Name.Length)];
                if (path == backupDirectory && blob.Name.Contains("bacpac")) test.Add(blob.Name.Replace(backupDirectory, string.Empty));
            }
        }


        //METHOD TWO
        Azure.Pageable<BlobItem> blobs = contCl.GetBlobs();

        foreach (BlobItem blob in blobs)
        {
            string path = blob.Name[..Math.Min(backupDirectory.Length, blob.Name.Length)];
            if (path == backupDirectory && blob.Name.Contains("bacpac")) rv.Add(blob.Name.Replace(backupDirectory, string.Empty));
        }

        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, you don't do anything with Azure Active Directory. AAD is an Identity and Access Management solution. It has nothing to do with files. You are just using an Azure Storage Account.

Comment: I assume, `.GetBlobHierarchy()` for `BlobStates.All` returns different versions of the same blobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobstates?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @VladDX Thanks. I fixed the Active Directory misnomer in my question. Also, setting `BlobStates.None` instead of `All` seems to have worked, even though there are no deleted blobs. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

> *method is stuffing duplicate values* into the `.bacpac` file list (i.e., for one .`bacpac` file, it adds two identical items into the list). I checked Active Directory and only saw one item.

My folder structure be like this:

[image]

When I tried with the same code I got the same output it not check duplicates and print all blobs like below:

**Output:**
[image]

To fix the issue you can use the below code in method 1:

Add the below condition along with the path check and bacpac check **`!test.Contains(blob.Name.Replace(backupDirectory, string.Empty))`**

**Code:**

```
public static List<string> GetBackupFiles(string dbName)
{
    string backupDirectory = dbName+ "/backup/sample1/" ;

    List<string> rv = new();

    BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = new BlobServiceClient(_StorageConnectionString);
    BlobContainerClient contCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer);

    Azure.Pageable<BlobHierarchyItem> blobHierarchyItems = contCl.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.All, BlobStates.All, "/", backupDirectory);
    List<string> test = new();
    foreach (BlobHierarchyItem blobHierarchyItem in blobHierarchyItems)
    {
        if (blobHierarchyItem.IsBlob)
        {
            BlobItem blob = blobHierarchyItem.Blob;
            string path = blob.Name[..Math.Min(backupDirectory.Length, blob.Name.Length)];
            if (path == backupDirectory && blob.Name.Contains("bacpac") && !test.Contains(blob.Name.Replace(backupDirectory, string.Empty))) test.Add(blob.Name.Replace(backupDirectory, string.Empty));
        }
    }
   
    return test;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: +1 because this is a valid solution. But I specifically asked for the solution to not be checking the new list for a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line under Method One

```
Azure.Pageable<BlobHierarchyItem> blobHierarchyItems = contCl.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.All,BlobStates.All, "/", backupDirectory);
```

By changing `BlobTraits.All` to `BlobTraits.None` solved the issue.

BlobTraits.All will retrieve blobs other than the active blobs.